# Get page count of RTF, TXT and XLS documents by OpenXml in C#

Tags: c#, openxml, office-interop, excel-interop

I want to count pages of the file with types of .rtf, .txt & .xls(x) through Open Xml.

One can say to use Office.InterOp assemblies (also to get counts of TXT & RTF and it works too). but I tried already and can't use as it takes so much time specifically on large files.

I've tried a lot but I couldn't or can say didn't get any reference on web.

By digging deep, for Excel files, I found something described on [THIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/officeocs/en-US/bab9718f-2dbf-422a-907a-f206ba8cf478/how-to-change-page-setup-property-of-excel-programmatically-without-reading-excel-for-printing?forum=exceldev)  site, but it just setups the page print settings.

Before printing, I want to have page count to be shown to user.

Also, I'm still trying to have any way for TXT & RTF files. Please share if this also can be via Open Xml and how.

Comment: Not feasible. Firstly, Open XML is not applicable to txt or rtf. Secondly, the Excel (or Word) application is required for the pagination - calculating how many pages the file lays out to when it's opened.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: may i know any other way available (except through Office.InterOp) to achieve what i want?